# Finding least number of bit sequence ORs to achieve all 1's?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to find anything that may help with this task: I have a variable number of bit sequences (that will all individually be the same length) and I need to find which combination of sequences would OR to all 1's, using as few sequences as possible. I was thinking to start with whichever sequence had the most 1's and try filling in the blanks, but since I haven't worked with bit comparisons really I didn't know if there was some algorithm or property of bit logic that would simplify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem, unfortunately, is NP-hard in the most general case by a reduction from the **[set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)**.  In the set cover problem, you have a collection of sets of elements, and want to find the smallest number of them whose union contains all the total elements.  You can easily reduce the set cover problem to your problem by constructing a bitvector for each set that has a 1 in each position if a given set has that item and a 0 otherwise.  The smallest number of bitvectors whose OR gives all 1s is then equivalent to the smallest group of sets whose union contains all elements.

For example, given the sets {a, b, e}, {b, c}, {b, d, f}, and {a, f}, you would get these bitvectors:

```
 {a, b, e}    110010
 {b, c}       011000
 {b, d, f}    010101
 {a, f}       100001
```

Since the set cover problem is known to be NP-hard, this means that unless P = NP there is no polynomial-time algorithm for your problem.  Worse, it is known that you cannot approximate the optimal solution within a factor of O(log n), where n is the number of total elements, in polynomial time.  You are probably best off looking for heuristics, or staying content with an O(log n) approximation using the **[greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you mean to say NP-complete? Although the two are similar, NP-complete is probably what you meant.

Comment: @KendallFrey- I meant NP-hard here.  NP-complete problems have to be decision problems, because NP is a class of decision problems.  However, the goal of the problem is to output the actual sequences whose OR is all 1s.  This means that the problem is a function problem.  Function problems can't be NP-complete, but they can be NP-hard, because it's possible to reduce NP-complete problems to them.

Comment: I checked the link for the set cover problem, and it mentioned NP-complete, so I assumed you meant NP-complete. :) Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. At least I can stop trying to find a simple solution and likely move to this greedy algorithm even though it won't be exact all the time. For my purpose close is good enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a bit about this problem and here's the idea I came up with:

- First you create for every bit a List and in every List you'll find every sequence that has a '1' on this bit. This takes O(n*m) beeing n the number of sequences and m the length of a particular sequence
- Then you count all occurences of every Bitsequence and throw all these Tuple of [List, Integer] in a structure (AVL Tree or Heap or whatever you like) and sort them. (I mean: the sequence 'a' occurs 15 times over all lists and sequence b 10 times). This takes again O(n*m) because O(nlogn) < O(n*m)
- In the next step you use the sequence with the highest priority and remove all lists of step one wich contain this sequence. Then you go back to step 2 until you have eliminated all lists. In the worst case you'll have to do this m times.

So in total we have a time of O(n * m^2)
Correct me if you I misunderstood a part of the question or if I did a mistake ;)
Here is a little example of what I mean:
Bit Strings:
a: 100101
b: 010001
c: 011100
d: 000010

So this will create the Lists:
L1: a
L2: b,c
L3: c
L4: a, c
L5: d
L6: a, b

Then we will count and sort:
a: 3
c: 3
b: 2
d: 1

So we take a in our final list and delete the following Lists:
L1, L4, L6

Now we count again:
c: 2
b: 1
d: 1

so we take c in our list and delete:
L2, L3
so we have only L5 left wich only contains d

So we have found our final minimal set: a, c, d

Comment: This is the greedy algorithm, which does not always work.  For example, try these bitvectors: 11111110000000, 00000001111111, 1000001000000, 01100000110000, 00011110001111.  The correct solution is to take 11111110000000 and 00000001111111.  However, if you go by priority, first you'd pick 00011110001111 (which covers eight uncovered elements), then 01100000110000 (which covers four uncovered elements), then 10000001000000 (which covers two).  This is not optimal.

Comment: oh i see. Thanks ;) Well I'll think about some possibilities but at 4:30am I don't think I'll produce something valuable...

Comment: Be aware that the problem is NP-hard, which means that in the last forty years no one has come up with an efficient algorithm for this problem.  I wouldn't lose sleep over it if you can't come up with something. :-)

Comment: Yes I know ;) But some exercise for the brain is never wrong. And currently I'm working so I can't go to sleep anyways ;)